# Different Design Layouts Connected to Same View Controller

Tags: swift

I'm creating a quiz app that will have multiple choice answers and/or written answers. Since this will mostly be the same code I want to have everything stored within a singular view controller. How can I make it so that when the user selects "multiple choice" the multiple-choice layout will load and vice versa?

Comment: How far have you gone through this problem, have you created all your views and layouts?

Comment: @Tadreik I've only made the views and layout for the multiple-choice design

Comment: Are you using storyboard to create your layout? If so, what does it look like? I can give you directions from there.